# Get Random itens from a config and put it in a custom inventory (Bukkit)

Tags: random, minecraft, bukkit

Well, Hello, I'm new member here and here's my first post on a dev forum.

I'm doing a quest plugin for minecraft.

Let's go to my question, I've a config.yml file with a list of quests numbered from 0 to 5, each number is a type of quests. Example:

Quest 0 type is Mine.
Quest 1 type is Farm.
Quest 2 type is KillMob.
Etc...

Each type have 15 different quests with a different objectives.

I wanna randomize the type and the quest itself and put 10 of them in the custom inventory I've created, how I do this? Can someone help me please? Any code you need I'll post here, Thanks!!

@Edit: 
    Config.yml:

```
 Diaria:
    Spawner:
        0:
            Nome: MissaoSpawner
            Tipo: Spawner
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
    Minerar:
        0:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos0
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        1:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos1
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        2:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos2
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        3:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos3
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        4:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos4
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        5:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos5
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        6:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos6
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        7:
            Nome: Minerar Bloco7
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        8:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos8
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        9:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos9
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        10:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos10
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        11:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos11
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        12:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos12
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        13:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos13
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
        14:
            Nome: Minerar Blocos14
            Tipo: Minerar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil

    Pescar:
        0:
            Nome: Pescar
            Tipo: Pescar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
    Votar:
        0:
            Nome: Voto
            Tipo: Votar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
    Plantar:
        0:
            Nome: Farm
            Tipo: Plantar
            Quantidade: 250
            Chance: 50
            Dificuldade: Facil
```

The file which I'm trying to add the randomize(That solution which is in my code didnt work for me, and I wanna work with chance in percentage):

```java
package me.missoes.Menus;

import me.missoes.Main;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class MenuFarm {

    public void menuFarm(Player p){
        Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null,27,"Missões de Farm");

        if (randomize() <= 1) {
            inv.setItem(2, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(3, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(4, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(5, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(6, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(11, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(12, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(13, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(14, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(15, Main.getInstance().getMissionManager().missaoFarm());
            inv.setItem(22, Main.getInstance().getItemManager().voltar());

            p.openInventory(inv);
        }
    }

    public int randomize(){

        List<Integer> numb = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numb.add(0);
        numb.add(1);
        numb.add(2);
        numb.add(3);
        numb.add(4);
        numb.add(5);
        numb.add(6);
        numb.add(7);
        numb.add(8);
        numb.add(9);
        numb.add(10);
        numb.add(11);
        numb.add(12);
        numb.add(13);
        numb.add(14);

        Random rng = new Random();

        int res = numb.get(rng.nextInt(numb.size()));

        return res;
    }
}
```

This is the file which is linked with tha above code:

```java
package me.missoes.Mission;

import me.missoes.Main;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MissionManager {

    Plugin p = Main.getPlugin(Main.class);

    public ItemStack missaoMinerar(){
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
        lore.add("Tipo: " + ChatColor.AQUA + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Minerar.0.Nome"));
        lore.add("Quantidade: " + ChatColor.RED + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Minerar.0.Quantidade"));
        lore.add("Dificuldade: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Minerar.0.Dificuldade"));
        lore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "§lCLIQUE PARA PEGAR");
        return Main.getInstance().getMissionBuilder().criarMissao(Material.PAPER, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Missão Diária", lore);
    }

    public ItemStack missaoFarm(){
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
        lore.add("Tipo: " + ChatColor.AQUA + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Plantar.0.Nome"));
        lore.add("Quantidade: " + ChatColor.RED + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Plantar.0.Quantidade"));
        lore.add("Dificuldade: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Plantar.0.Dificuldade"));
        lore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "§lCLIQUE PARA PEGAR");
        return Main.getInstance().getMissionBuilder().criarMissao(Material.PAPER, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Missão Diária", lore);
    }

    public ItemStack missaoPesca(){
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
        lore.add("Tipo: " + ChatColor.AQUA + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Pescar.0.Nome"));
        lore.add("Quantidade: " + ChatColor.RED + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Pescar.0.Quantidade"));
        lore.add("Dificuldade: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Pescar.0.Dificuldade"));
        lore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "§lCLIQUE PARA PEGAR");
        return Main.getInstance().getMissionBuilder().criarMissao(Material.PAPER, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Missão Diária", lore);
    }

    public ItemStack missaoSpawner(){
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
        lore.add("Tipo: " + ChatColor.AQUA + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Spawner.0.Nome"));
        lore.add("Quantidade: " + ChatColor.RED + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Spawner.0.Quantidade"));
        lore.add("Dificuldade: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Spawner.0.Dificuldade"));
        lore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "§lCLIQUE PARA PEGAR");
        return Main.getInstance().getMissionBuilder().criarMissao(Material.PAPER, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Missão Diária", lore);
    }

    public ItemStack missaoVoto(){
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
        lore.add("Tipo: " + ChatColor.AQUA + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Votar.0.Nome"));
        lore.add("Quantidade: " + ChatColor.RED + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Votar.0.Quantidade"));
        lore.add("Dificuldade: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Votar.0.Dificuldade"));
        lore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "§lCLIQUE PARA PEGAR");
        return Main.getInstance().getMissionBuilder().criarMissao(Material.PAPER, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Missão Diária", lore);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, please post any code you have tried to write to solve this problem.

Comment: Files added, thanks for the help!

Comment: We're not quite there, please post your code directly into the post, do not use links.

Comment: Edited, sorry and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you but I just got you the solution here:

```java
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public void menuFarm(Player p) {
        Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, "Missões de Farm");
        ItemStack[] chosen = new ItemStack[10];
        boolean[] already = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_ITEMS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_ITEMS; i ++) {
            int r;
            do {
                r = rnd.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_ITEMS);
            } while (already[r]);
            already[r] = true;
            chosen[i] = getItem(r);
        }
        inv.setItem(2, chosen[0]);
        inv.setItem(3, chosen[1]);
        inv.setItem(4, chosen[2]);
        inv.setItem(5, chosen[3]);
        inv.setItem(6, chosen[4]);
        inv.setItem(11, chosen[5]);
        inv.setItem(12, chosen[6]);
        inv.setItem(13, chosen[7]);
        inv.setItem(14, chosen[8]);
        inv.setItem(15, chosen[9]);
        inv.setItem(22, Main.getInstance().getItemManager().voltar());
        p.openInventory(inv);
    }

    private ItemStack getItem(int r) {
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
        lore.add("Tipo: " + ChatColor.AQUA + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Plantar." + r + ".Nome"));
        lore.add("Quantidade: " + ChatColor.RED + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Plantar." + r + ".Quantidade"));
        lore.add("Dificuldade: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getConfig().get("Diaria.Plantar." + r + ".Dificuldade"));
        lore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "§lCLIQUE PARA PEGAR");
        return Main.getInstance().getMissionBuilder().criarMissao(Material.PAPER, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Missão Diária", lore);
    }
```

I won't go into the details but basically it first gets 10 random items and checks if there are no duplicates and then finally sets the items into the inventory.

The getItem methode works with the id to get the corresponding strings in the config file (Nicely done to chose numbers to store your quests)